# How do I create a form that once submitted, it opens google search results in a new tab?

Tags: html, css

I want to create an input form that will take the input text and show the google search results thereof in a new tab.

The new tab should be google's SERP.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<div id="searchContainer">
<form name="" action="" type="">
        <input type="text" name="field" id="field" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>
```

How do I go about doing this? Do I need to use a javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview and use Google API,its pretty simple